# Swift generics and protocols issue

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to push MVVM patterns on my application, but I've found that quite difficult using Swift and Generics. Example:

I have a `Comic` struct on my model layer. But I want my `viewControllers` to consume objects conforming `ComicViewModel` protocol in order to increase separation of concerns.

I'm wrapping the model structs in a class called `Box` defined like this:

```
public class Box<T> {
    public let value: T
    public init(_ value: T) { self.value = value }
}
```

This is used only to wrap the actual return value in a `Result` enum like the one explained [here](http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/error-handling-in-swift)

However, the Swift compiler doesn't seem to like the cast from `Comic` to `ComicViewModel` even if I'm clearly defining that

```
func sampleComics() -> Box<Comic> {...}
protocol ComicViewModel {...}
extension Comic : ComicViewModel {...}

func fetchComicsViewModel() -> Box<ComicViewModel> {
    return sampleComics() //ERROR
}
```

Full playground available [here](https://gist.github.com/piercifani/23640a8211a0e891c4a5/).

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad to say, Swift doesn't perform implicit casting like that. As of now, you have to re-`Box()` the value.

```
func fetchComicsViewModel() -> Box<ComicViewModel> {
    return Box(sampleComics().value)
}
```

Comment: See this topic on the devforums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1101023#1101023

Comment: So sad to hear this... Because it's not as simple as `Box`ing the value, I have a lot of other layers to go deep and convert in order to work around this compiler limitation